# xamarin app flagging error about not support tag

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Finished building my xamarin app on android, now moving to ios to test.

Obv layout is different so attempting to tidy up.

On Android...

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="shoppingCartImg" Icon="shoppingCartImg.png" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Activated="ShoppingCartPressed"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="{Binding NoItemsInShoppingCart}" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Activated="ShoppingCartPressed"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

showed the shopping cart image and the number of items in the shopping cart...

However on IOS it only shows the number of items...

I have added  `<Image Source="shoppingCartImg.png"/>` inside a stackLayout inside the main grid and it appears, so the problem is with the toolbarItem. I found online to put code inside separate tags like follows:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
  <OnPlatform.iOS>
    ...
  </OnPlatform.iOS>
  <OnPlatform.Android>
    ...
  </OnPlatform.Android>
  <OnPlatform.WinPhone>
    ...
  </OnPlatform.WinPhone>
</OnPlatform>
```

</ContentPage.Content>

but when I try this it flags error:

```
 <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

  
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">

  <OnPlatform.iOS>
     <Image Source="shoppingCartImg.png">
<Image.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer
            Tapped="OnImageNameTapped"
            NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
```

</Image.GestureRecognizers>

```
  </OnPlatform.iOS>

  <OnPlatform.Android>
 <ToolbarItem Name="shoppingCartImg" Icon="shoppingCartImg.png" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Activated="ShoppingCartPressed"/>
    
  </OnPlatform.Android>

</OnPlatform>

    <ToolbarItem Text="{Binding NoItemsInShoppingCart}" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Activated="ShoppingCartPressed"/>
   
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

but this flags an error with the toolbarItem inside the .android tags with

**property 'android' does not support values of type 'toolbaritem'. The specified value cannot be assigned. The following type was expected 'view'**

Comment: Have you tried setting the Priority value to different values for the two different items?

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the reply. Just tried what you have suggested but unfortunately it didnt work, still getting same error

Comment: Did you try that without all of the OnPlatform markup?   And have you tried just displaying the icon and not the text?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the Xaml below in both Android and iOS OF Xamarin.forms. It could show the icon well.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<ToolbarItem Name="shoppingCartImg" Icon="shoppingCartImg.png" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Activated="ShoppingCartPressed"/>
<ToolbarItem Text="{Binding NoItemsInShoppingCart}" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Activated="ShoppingCartPressed"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Please check the icon path. Have you set the icon(shoppingCartImg.png) in ios? If you add the image with the same name of `shoppingCartImg`, it would display the image in toolbar with no specific implementation.

You could try to add images to an asset catalog image set.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=windows#adding-images-to-an-asset-catalog-image-set